# Most recent mail Notification in python and Imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

I would like to ask how to properly create solution for notification via `imaplib`. I establish a connection and then I have to update it somehow so I can get the most recent mail in my inbox.

Problem is that with this solution it will eventually break with the following error

> socket error: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:2396)

I understand it as that I overhelm server with my requests and commands such as `imap.noop()` or `imap.recent()` should listen and then I can login and update my state. Although it does not work as well.

this is part of my code which should be repaired. I´m trying to get the UID of the most recent mail within second it was delivered to the mailbox.

```
def signal_awaiter_system():
    latest_email_uid = ''
    second_latest_uid = ""
    first_skip = 0 
    print_counter = 0
    while True:
        res,state = imap.recent()
        if state == True and res == "OK":
            print("new login")
            login("Inbox")
        result, data = imap.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search and return uids instead  
        ids = codecs.decode(data[0],"UTF-8") # data is a list.
        latest_email_uid = int(ids.split()[-1])
        time.sleep(0.1)
        try:
            if latest_email_uid != second_latest_uid and first_skip == 0:
                first_skip = 1
                print("Init jsem přeskočil")
            elif latest_email_uid != second_latest_uid and first_skip == 1:
                alert = get_alert()
                to_do,market, contract_size, datem = alert
                print("alerty by se měly rozeslat")
                return to_do,market, contract_size
```

Comment: imaplib can’t really effectively do that.  The right move is to use a library that supports IMAP IDLE, and the server will “push” notifications to you, but it may take up to a minute on some servers.

Comment: Or alternatively, if you run the mailserver, have the mail server run a script when the message is incoming, rather than trying to pull it with IMAP.  Nearly all popular mail server software can be made to run a script when a message arrives via SMTP.

Comment: Thank you for the time you have took to answer me. I really appreciate it. I also found IMAP idle as well but when I installed imaplib2 even though I saw idle function in the library I was not able to call it anyhow. But still even with some delay it may be a solution for me. Thanks again

Comment: So I was able to implement idle quite succesfully. I also restart Idle after 10 minutes just to be sure, it will work properly.
But yet, I still running into same issue as before. After few hours (probably around 10-12) I will get this error:
 'socket error: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)' . Before I thought it is due to my exercive connections but now, when Idle is at place I connect only when Idle indicate new mail in the Inbox. 
so what might cause this issue and more importantly how to fix it ?
Thank you

Comment: In _any_ network program you have to expect and deal with Network Errors. When you get one, wait a few seconds, and attempt to reconnect. So put the whole thing in a loop!  Bonus if you add exponential back off.

Comment: Hello again, I quite reworked a lot in the code and somehow can´t get rid of this error.
'socket error: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:2396)'

I am convinced that my code is now not abusing gmail´s servers so much as before but still I get it within 2 hours on debugger or 12 hours on live.
My main problem is that it is even avoiding try and except and bassically it turns the whole bot in some kind sfere between turn on and off. Once I restart it manually it will work ok for next few hours.

Comment: You don't get rid of the answer.  You handle it, and reconnect.  Every internet server will occasionally close a socket on you, you should wait a few seconds and try to reconnect!  If you can't reconnect right away, wait a little longer and try again, and so on.